# Lined title in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a lined title with flexbox. It works but the text in the title goes to the next line, which is not what I want - it should all stay in one line.

```css
.hr {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  height: 3px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='hr'>
  <div class='title'>
    Apes are cool animals
  </div>
  <div class='line'></div>
</div>

<div class='hr'>
  <div class='title'>
    Aren't they?
  </div>
  <div class='line'></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6q2h7a5/)

Expected Result:
https://i.gyazo.com/3164ae24d7fd2402fa711126d04319b1.png

Comment: note that `inline-block` can be removed as it's useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a rule to stop the text from wrapping with `.title { white-space: nowrap; }`:

```css
.hr {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  height: 3px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='hr'>
  <div class='title'>
    Apes are cool animals
  </div>
  <div class='line'></div>
</div>

<div class='hr'>
  <div class='title'>
    Aren't they?
  </div>
  <div class='line'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is by using `flex: 1` instead of `width: 100%` in `.line`. This makes the line as long as it needs to be in order to cover the space left by the title.

**Example:**

```css
.hr {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  height: 3px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='hr'>
  <div class='title'>
    Apes are cool animals
  </div>
  <div class='line'></div>
</div>

<div class='hr'>
  <div class='title'>
    Aren't they?
  </div>
  <div class='line'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `flex-shrink: 0` to the `title` (the *default* is `flex-shrink: 1` for a *flex item* - see demo below:

```css
.hr {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  height: 3px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class='hr'>
  <div class='title'>
    Apes are cool animals
  </div>
  <div class='line'></div>
</div>

<div class='hr'>
  <div class='title'>
    Aren't they?
  </div>
  <div class='line'></div>
</div>
```